# C# Inheritance concept advise

Tags: c#, oop

I have a small query related to OOP concept in C#.

**I have an interface**

```
interface intf
{
   string Hello();
}
```

**A base class**

```
public class BaseClass
{
   public string Hello()
   {
      return "Hello of base class called";
   }
}
```

**A child class that is derived from `BaseClass` and implements the interface intf as well**

```
public class ChildClass : BaseClass, intf
{
  string  Hello()
  {
     return "Hello of child class called";
  }
}
```

Now my question is that when I create an object of `ChildClass` then when I call the hello method it always calls the hello method of `BaseClass`. Firstly, why does it call the `Hello` of the `BaseClass`? Secondly, how can I call the `Hello` of the `ChildClass`?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      ChildClass obj = new ChildClass();
      MessageBox.Show(obj.Hello());
}
```

Comment: Why declare the method on the interface too? What are you trying to accomplish? Also, are you aware of the fact that you can explicitly implement an interface?

Comment: Well i am just trying to learn the conepts and yes i am aware that if i do intf.hello this will call my interface method. thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why call the Hello of base**

Your child class implements the interface, so it is considered to contain a public Hello method. But in your child class, Hello is not public. The Hello method in base class is public and is considered to be the implementation of the interface.

**How to call Hello of child class**

Make the Hello in child class public. Then it will be considered to an implementation of the interface.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you did not provide an access modifier for `Hello` in `ChildClass`. This makes it private by default. To access that method from outside of the class, mark it `public` (or `internal` if using it from the same namespace). As it stands now, the only publicly visible `Hello` method *is* the base class method.

Secondly, once you have resolved the access issue, `Hello` will hide the method in the base. If this is intentional, it is advisable to use the `new` keyword with the method

```
public new string Hello()
```

If your intention was *not* to hide the method but instead to override it, mark the method as virtual in the base class and use the override keyword in the child.

```
public class ChildClass : BaseClass, intf
{
    public override string Hello()
    {
        return "Hello of child class called";
    }
}

public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual string Hello()
    {
        return "Hello of base class called";
    }
}
```

This will allow you to *always* call the child method unless you *explicitly* call the base method from within the child.

Calls like this from the outside world

```
((BaseClass)child).Hello();
(child as BaseClass).Hello();
BaseClass baseClass = new ChildClass();
baseClass.Hello();
```

Will result in the child method being used.

Calls like this from *within* the child class

```
base.Hello();
```

Will result in the base class method being used.

Answer (score 2):

Declare the method in the base class `virtual` and then `override` it in the child class. That way, the virtual call will resolve to the child class instead of the parent class.

**Update:**
To answer the question about why it still the base method even after you put `new` in the method declaration:

By default, class members are private. Therefore, since you did not mark the method as public, the method is private. Therefore the programs is force to called the base method as it's the only one that's accessible.

Comment: Also, the method on the child class should be `public`

Comment: Esteban, Thanks for the reply and i agree that it will call the hello of child when i use the virtual and override keywords. Now let me modify the code little bit and add new keyword to my child class hello key if i check now it still calls the hello of base. WHY?

Comment: check for errors and warnings when you build your project.  If you don't have your `virtual` and `override` keywords right, you'll get a warning like: "'App.ChildClass.Hello()' hides inherited member 'App.BaseClass.Hello()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended."

Answer (score 0):

The way you've currently declared your methods, the method `Hello()` in the `ChildClass` in inaccessible, and hence the public method in the `BaseClass` is called. What you really want is what Esteban said though, declare the base method `public virtual`, the derived method `public override`, otherwise your method is just shadowing the base class method.

Answer (score 0):

As other said, make the Hello method in the Child class public override.

Also, IMHO, you should implement the interface in the base class, not the child class. But that has nothing to do with the fact your method doesn't get called.